# SQL order by Date from concatenated Month and Year string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting query with an aggregate that orders incorrectly as it orders the dates alphanumerically as they are strings(VARCHARS).  It is as follows.

```
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.DeploymentReport
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeploymentReport
@Date DATE
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 6 DATENAME(MONTH,DeployDate) + ' - '  + DATENAME(YEAR,DeployDate) AS 'Month', 
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 3 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'High',
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 2 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'Med',
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 1 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'Low'      
FROM dbo.ChangeEvaluationForm cef
INNER JOIN dbo.Package pac
ON cef.ChangeId = pac.ChangeId
INNER JOIN dbo.SDMTicket sdm
ON pac.PackageId = sdm.PackageId
WHERE DeployDate < @Date
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, DeployDate) + ' - '  + DATENAME(YEAR,DeployDate)
ORDER BY DATENAME(MONTH, DeployDate) + ' - '  + DATENAME(YEAR,DeployDate) DESC
END
GO

DECLARE @DateSelected DATETIME
SET @DateSelected = CONVERT(DATE,'2017-12-30')
EXECUTE dbo.DeploymentReport @Date = @DateSelected;
```

The result looks like the following

[image]

As you can see the months are sorted alphanumerically instead of by DATE.

Now I am absolutely brutal with aggregate queries, so my struggle is changing the ORDER BY line so that it somehow parses the year and month from the 'Month' column, and Orders by year, and then month, without changing the structure of the data return.

Is this at all possible, or is the approach I'm thinking of not possible or the wrong way of thinking of it?

Comment: just don't order by DATENAME. just use "ORDER BY DATEPART(mm,DeployDate) and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `year(DeployDate)` and `month(DepolyDate)` to your group by clause, since you are already using `datename(year, DeployDate)` and `datename(month, DeployDate)` in the group by clause it should have no effect at all, other then the fact that it will allow you to use them on the order by clause:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeploymentReport
@Date DATE
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 6 DATENAME(MONTH,DeployDate) + ' - '  + DATENAME(YEAR,DeployDate) AS 'Month', 
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 3 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'High',
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 2 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'Med',
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 1 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'Low'      
FROM dbo.ChangeEvaluationForm cef
INNER JOIN dbo.Package pac
ON cef.ChangeId = pac.ChangeId
INNER JOIN dbo.SDMTicket sdm
ON pac.PackageId = sdm.PackageId
WHERE DeployDate < @Date
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, DeployDate) + ' - '  + DATENAME(YEAR,DeployDate), Year(DeployDate), Month(DeployDate)
ORDER BY Year(DeployDate) DESC, Month(DeployDate) DESC
END
GO
```

Comment: This works wonderfully too, and I actually opted to use this solution instead for readability.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Shift the `GROUP BY` logic into a subquery that uses a more "date-like" grouping column, then apply the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` in the outer query:

```
SELECT TOP 6 DATENAME(MONTH,DeployDate) + ' - '  + DATENAME(YEAR,DeployDate) AS 'Month',
      High,Med,Low
FROM (
       SELECT DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DeployDate),0) as DeployDate,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 3 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'High',
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 2 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'Med',
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 1 THEN 1 END),0) AS 'Low'      
FROM dbo.ChangeEvaluationForm cef
INNER JOIN dbo.Package pac
ON cef.ChangeId = pac.ChangeId
INNER JOIN dbo.SDMTicket sdm
ON pac.PackageId = sdm.PackageId
WHERE DeployDate < @Date
GROUP BY DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DeployDate),0)
) t
ORDER BY DeployDate DESC
```

Here, `DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DeployDate),0)` rounds the `DeployDate` column down to midnight at the start of the 1st of its relevant month - so all `DeployDate` values within the same month generate the same value. Grouping on this column is then the equivalent of grouping on your string, but it's still a `datetime` and so can be used correctly in the outer `ORDER BY`. (And can still be used to extract the month and year components in  the outer `SELECT`)

Answer (score 1):

Your time spans are ordered, so I would just choose an arbitrary value in each one and do:

```
ORDER BY MIN(DeployDate) DESC
```

I should note that I much prefer the format YYYY-MM; one important reason is that it can be ordered correctly.